# Add one row in a data frame to all rows of another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 data frames:

```
A <- data.frame(x = c(1,4), y = c(3,5))
B <- data.frame(x = c(3,6), y = c(7,9))
```

A

```
x   y
1   3
4   5
```

B

```
x    y
2    4
3    6
```

I want to add all rows in `A` to the first row of `B`. My desired output data frame is:

```
x    y
3    7
6    9
```

I tried `B[1, ] + A` but it did not work:

```
#Error in Ops.data.frame(A, B[1, ]) : 
#  ‘+’ only defined for equally-sized data frames
```

Really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without converting everything into matrix and working with matrix, we can use:

```
mapply("+", A, B[1, ])
```

Another way (more similar to using matrices), is:

```
A + B[rep.int(1, nrow(A)),]
```

Comment: My approach seems pretty cumbersome, but does seem to work: `do.call(rbind, apply(A, 1, function(x) {B[1,] + x}))`

Answer (score 2):

We can also replicate the first row of 'B' and add with 'A'

```
unlist(B[1,])[col(A)] + A
#  x y
#1 3 7
#2 6 9
```